# OpenCV return keypoints coordinates and area from blob detection, Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, blob, keypoint

I followed a blob detection example (using `cv2.SimpleBlobDetector`) and successfully detected the blobs in my binary image. But then I don't know how to extract the coordinates and area of the keypoints. Here are the code for the blob detections:

```
# I skipped the parameter setting part. 
    blobParams = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_Params()
    blobVer = (cv2.__version__).split('.')
    if int(blobVer[0]) < 3:
        detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector(blobParams)
    else:
        detector = cv2.SimpleBlobDetector_create(blobParams)

    # Detect Blobs
    keypoints_black = detector.detect(255-black_blob)
    trans_blobs = cv2.drawKeypoints(gray_video_crop, \
        keypoints_white, np.array([]), (0,0,255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
```

So the variable `keypoints_black` contains the information of the blob(s). When I printed the variable it looked something like this (2 blobs were found):

```
KeyPoint 0x10b10b870, KeyPoint 0x10b1301b0
```

So how to I get the coordinates of the centre of mass of the keypoints and their area so that I can send them as osc messages for interaction.

Comment: Try printing `dir(keypoint)` where `keypoint is obviously a keypoint :) That should give you a list of methods. Also, you can try `tuple(keypoint)` to see if it's convertible.

Comment: I tried tuple(keypoint) it it returned the same, just in tuple rather than array.

Comment: And the dir(keypoint) did return a buch of methods: ['__delattr__', '__delitem__', 
   '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', 
  #'__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', 
  #'__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', 
  #'__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', 
  #'__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 
  #'append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', ]. But dont know what next

Comment: while Joao provided the answer, my sugestion for tuple was of course meant on a *keypoint*, not the list of objects....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `pt` property:

```
keypoints = detector.detect(frame) #list of blobs keypoints
x = keypoints[i].pt[0] #i is the index of the blob you want to get the position
y = keypoints[i].pt[1]
```

[Some documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_feature_detectors.html#Point2f%20pt)

Comment: Thanks for the link to documentation!

Comment: why is the coordinate a float?

Answer (score 11):

If you have a list of keypoints. Then you can print as shown below

```
for keyPoint in keyPoints:
    x = keyPoint.pt[0]
    y = keyPoint.pt[1]
    s = keyPoint.size
```

Edit: Size determines the diameter of the meaningful keypoint neighborhood. You can use that size and roughly calculate the area of the blob.

Comment: The attribute `.size` is the diameter of the blob, not its area.

Comment: @Delgan No where I said `.size` means area in my answer. Please read it properly.

Comment: You are saying it implicitly, as the author asked "how to I get the coordinates of the centre of mass of the keypoints and their area". Anyone reading your answer will wrongly deduce from it than `.size` returns the area of the blob.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer really saved a lot of work for me today :)

Comment: Karthik didn't say size is area; only that size determines diameter which can be used to estimate the area. So, confusing since begs the questions: Do you mean size 'is' diameter? Is the blob area the area of a circle with that diameter? How is that an estimate? ... So, the comment about reading 'properly' is overly defensive ... and triggering. Delgan's clarification is factual and I think useful as such... although worded somewhat triggering as well. Please strive for civility. ... Sadly, although the OP asked about area, there is no _clear_ answer to that part of the question.