# what does keypoint in opencv python store after ORB keypoint detection

Tags: python, opencv

i detect keypoints using orb algorithm of opencv using python . when i try to print the keypoints it shows something like

```
<KeyPoint 0x7f5c50e41c00>
<KeyPoint 0x7f5c50e41c30>
<KeyPoint 0x7f5c50e41c60>
<KeyPoint 0x7f5c50e41c90>
<KeyPoint 0x7f5c50e41cc0>
<KeyPoint 0x7f5c50e41cf0>
<KeyPoint 0x7f5c50e41d20>
...
```

what does it mean ?isnt keypoint supposed to store x,y,angle,class_id,orientation , etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV return keypoints coordinates and area from blob detection, Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30807214/opencv-return-keypoints-coordinates-and-area-from-blob-detection-python)

Comment: You need access members like this: `print(keypoints[0].pt, keypoints[0].angle,...)`

Comment: Part of the question is duplicated. I'd like to know the answer to the wider question "What does it mean?" - how to dereference the individual object addresses (e.g. 0x7f5c50e41c00) so that the keypoints can be cached/pickled?